# Difference Between Shamayim and Rakia

Tags: words, parashat-bereishit

In parshas Berashis, the words Shamayim and Rakia keep on coming up. someone asked me what is the difference between the 2, and I had no idea.

Comment: What's the difference between יבשה and ארץ?

Comment: There are 7 of them - and they are defined in Chagiga 12b - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.12b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @DannySchoemann I was thinking along the same line. I think you have an answer.

Comment: @DanF - go ahead - I don't have the time to write it up.